# Nginx. Rewrite to static file. Not trivial

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, static

actually my first question on stackoverflow, because case is not so easy.
I want nginx to rewrite all requests to static file appending requested url, and i achieved this easily with this rule

```
location / {
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }

        location @rewriteapp {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html#!$1 break;
}
```

BUT this is resulting in 404 and in log i see exactly how this should work, but it isn't.

```
2016/11/21 11:53:33 [error] 5220#6856: *1 "C:/Projects/ProCongress/web/index.html#!/index.html" is not found (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: congress, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "congress"
```

web/index.html#!/index.html - this part is acutally absolultley right, and should work correctly, but isn't...

Comment: Try changing `break` to `redirect`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot, i was literally stuck...